# LastChildFill with group of controls

Tags: wpf

I have a DockPanel with a row defined as LastChildFill="true", and the last item in the row is two independent controls representing a file picker- a TextBox for a file path, followed by a Button which displays an open file dialog (to populate the textbox). I would like to dock this grouping of controls to end of the row such that the TextBox, not the Button, is stretched to fill the space. Is that possible?

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1"
       Margin="3"
       LastChildFill="True">
    <!-- * additional controls omitted * -->
    <TextBox x:Name="TExecutable"
             Width="200"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
             Text="{Binding Locale[event_SampleExecutable],
                            Source={StaticResource PluginViewModel}}"/>
    <Button Margin="3 0 0 0"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            Command="{Binding SelectExecutableCommand}"
            Content="{Binding Locale[event_SelectExecutableText],
                              Source={StaticResource PluginViewModel}}" />
</DockPanel>
```

[image: DockPanel Row]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do following things:

1. Place Button first in XAML i.e. above TextBox so that *TextBox will be LastChild in DockPanel* and will be candidate for full stretch.
2. Remove harcoded width from TextBox because you want that to be stretch.
3. Set `DockPanel.Dock="Right"` on button so that it will be placed on right of textBox.
4. Set `DockPanel.Dock="Left"` on textBox.

   ```
   <DockPanel Grid.Row="1"
              Margin="3"
              LastChildFill="True">
       <!-- * additional controls omitted * -->
       <Button Margin="3 0 0 0"
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
               DockPanel.Dock="Right"
               Command="{Binding SelectExecutableCommand}"
               Content="{Binding Locale[event_SelectExecutableText],
                             Source={StaticResource PluginViewModel}}" />
       <TextBox x:Name="TExecutable"
                DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Text="{Binding Locale[event_SampleExecutable],
                          Source={StaticResource PluginViewModel}}"/>
   </DockPanel>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

wrap with Grid:

```
<DockPanel 
       Margin="3"
       LastChildFill="True">
    <!-- * additional controls omitted * -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="TExecutable"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 Text="{Binding Locale[event_SampleExecutable],
                                Source={StaticResource PluginViewModel}}"/>
        <Button Margin="3 0 0 0" Grid.Column="1"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Command="{Binding SelectExecutableCommand}"
                Content="{Binding Locale[event_SelectExecutableText],
                                  Source={StaticResource PluginViewModel}}" />
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: I tried this and the result was a 1px wide TextBox and a fully stretched Button.